# Regex to select homepage and index.html only

Tags: regex

I'm trying to select the homepage and the index.html (which are the same page) via regex but no luck so far.

What I want:

example.com

example.com/index.html

What I don't want:

example.com/everything-else

Here is what I tried

```
\.com|index.html -> Selects index.html only. No other pages on the website but nor the .com either

/^\.ie$/|index\.html -> No luck
```

Environment - Google Tag Manager
It enables me to trigger certain events based on pages, which I am trying to select using regex.

Comment: Please give more examples of input strings and what the desired outcome.

Comment: Thats not valid regex, that's a wildcard path!

Comment: What is the language/tool?

Comment: Eddited to make it clearer. Sorry

Comment: im not sure how Google Tag Manager works but maybe `/|index.html` or `|index.html` ? Anyway the question is more about how Google Tag Manager works (with which part it will compare the regex)

Answer (score 0):

Found out a way:

/(index.html)?$

Thanks for the help anyway :]